# Generate number for object added to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I´ve created an ArrayList where I want to add participants for a event based on user input. Every participant added will automatically get a start number where the first one should get the number 100. For every participant added after that the start number will increase by one (101, 102, 103 etc.) Any suggestions how to do this?

This is my code for this so far:

```
public void addParticipant() {

    int startNumber = 100;

    System.out.println("First name: ");
    String name = readString();
    System.out.println("Last name: ");
    String lastName = readString();
    System.out.println("Team: ");
    String team = readString();

    allParticipants.add(new Participant(name, lastName, team, startNumber));

    System.out.println(name + " " + lastName + " from " + team + " with number " + startNumber + " added \n");
```

Comment: Just use the size of `allParticipants` and add it to the `startNumber`?

Comment: There are many possible implementations that achieves that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two easy ways of doing this.

**First Way:** Instead of storing the participant number in a local variable, store it in a field (instance variable), and increment it by one each time you add a new participant. I'd be something like this:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private int startNumber = 100;

    // any other code in the class...

    public void addParticipant() {

        System.out.println("First name: ");
        String name = readString();
        System.out.println("Last name: ");
        String lastName = readString();
        System.out.println("Team: ");
        String team = readString();

        allParticipants.add(new Participant(name, lastName, startNumber));

        System.out.println(name + " " + lastName + " from " + team + " with number " + startNumber + " added \n");

        // Increment field startNumber
        startNumber = startNumber + 1;
    }
}
```

**Second Way:** Use the size of the ArrayList as the counter. This is what I mean:

```
public class SomeClass {

    // any other code in the class...

    public void addParticipant() {

        int startNumber = allParticipants.size() + 100;

        System.out.println("First name: ");
        String name = readString();
        System.out.println("Last name: ");
        String lastName = readString();
        System.out.println("Team: ");
        String team = readString();

        allParticipants.add(new Participant(name, lastName, startNumber));

        System.out.println(name + " " + lastName + " from " + team + " with number " + startNumber + " added \n");
    }
}
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Store startNumber as an instance variable instead of a local variable in the function. Increment the variable after you add a new participant.

```
private int startNumber = 100;

public void addParticipant(){
    // Assign the startNumber to the new participant.
    startNumber++;
}
```